# Xcode 4: Close all documents?

Tags: xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts

I often do Control-Command-W to close a document. Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu option to close all documents?

Comment: all i see from the pdf i use is close all windows, Alt-Command-W

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Holding down Control-Command-W seems like the best way to close all documents in a single window.

Comment: The year is 2017, and we still can't close all documents with a single command (keystroke or menu). Sad.