# How to close all document (editor) windows in XCode 4 without closing the project itself?

Tags: xcode

In XCode 3.x pressing the red "close" button of any editor window, while holding the Option key, closes all editor windows. In XCode 4, the same thing closes all windows but also closes the project itself. Is there a way to close them without closing the project in Xcode 4?

Comment: Already answered here ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281399/xcode-4-close-all-documents